# Team synchronization on working sets in egit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

When I right click on any working set(In package,Navigator etc view) I am not getting synchronization option under **Team** Menu. See Picture below. Note that all projects in this working set are present in the git repository.

[image]

Is there any way to synchronize single or multiple(group of i.e working set) projects with git repository without switching to synchronization view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the open [EGit bug 311299](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=311299) for making the Team menu work on Working Sets (contributions welcome!).

For launching synchronization for a repository, it's enough to select one of the projects and selecting Team > Synchronize Workspace.